# Stub a single package-protected method for purposes of testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class that takes some objects as parameters. I can create real dependency objects and create a real Object Under Test. I have one method that is package-protected that makes a network call. I want to stub only this one in Mockito. Caveat: The network-called method is called internally from another method, therefore a regular Mockito spy will not work.
Example:

```
public class AddressSearcher {
    private final AddressSearcherSettings settings;
    private final AddressList addressList;
    private final OtherDependency otherDependency;

    public AddressSearcher(
        final AddressSearcherSettings settings,
        final AddressList addressList,
        final OtherDependency otherDependency
    ) {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.addressList = addressList;
        this.otherDependency = otherDependency;
    }

    public Domain checkAddress(String address) {
        if (addressList.contains(address)) {
            return addressList.get(address)
        }

        if (this.getDomainFromIp().isNotEmpty()) {
            return this.getDomainFromIp();
        }

        return EmptyDomain();

    }

    Domain getDomainFromIp(String address) {
        // do network call to search from domain from ip Address
    }

}
```

As mentioned in the intro, I've tried mocks and spies. I wasted a lot of time with spies, because I did not know that when called internally, the spy calls the real method.

```
@Test
public void checkAddressTest() {
    ...
    AddressSearcher realAddressSearcher = new AddressSearcher(realSettings, realAddressList, realOtherDependency);
    AddressSearcher spiedAddressSearcher = Mockito.spy(realAddressSearcher);

// works as expected
    Mockito.doReturn(new Domain("Google")).when(this.spiedAddressSearcher).getDomainFromIp("8.8.8.8");
    assertEqual(new Domain("Google"), this.spiedAddressSearcher.getDomainFromIp("8.8.8.8"))

// Using checkAddress, which internally calls getDomainFromIp
    assertEqual(new Domain("Google"), this.spiedAddressSearcher.checkAddress("8.8.8.8"))
// FALSE, expected GoogleDomain, got EmptyDomain
}
```

I just want to stub this single network call with Mockito.
I am able to in Jmockit very easily.
I am not able to change the code and make the network call an injectable dependency (which could in turn be mocked more easily)

Comment: I would move the network code into another component and mock this in your test. I know you've said that you aren't allowed to change the code, but refactoring for testability is a necessary part of writing unit tests. Whoever has asked you to write the tests needs to understand that.

Comment: As tgdavies suggested, extracting network communication is the preferred option. Subclassing and overriding `getDomainFromIp` is an option if you really cannot change the code under test - it is not elegant, but gets the job done.